# How to reduce this script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use loop in this script,but i don't have any idea how to do it.

Here it is that i have tried:

```
$('#choice').change(function(){

        if ($('#choice').val()=='')

        {
             $('#topic1').hide();
             $('#topic2').hide();
             $('#topic3').hide();
             $('#topic4').hide();
             $('#topic5').hide();
             $('#topic6').hide();
             $('#topic7').hide();
        }if ($('#choice').val()=='1')
        {
             $('#topic1').show();
             $('#topic2').hide();
             $('#topic3').hide();
             $('#topic4').hide();
             $('#topic5').hide();
             $('#topic6').hide();
             $('#topic7').hide();
        }
        if ($('#choice').val()=='2')
        {
             $('#topic1').show();
             $('#topic2').show();
             $('#topic3').hide();
             $('#topic4').hide();
             $('#topic5').hide();
             $('#topic6').hide();
             $('#topic7').hide();
        }
        if ($('#choice').val()=='3')
        {
             $('#topic1').show();
             $('#topic2').show();
             $('#topic3').show();
             $('#topic4').hide();
             $('#topic5').hide();
             $('#topic6').hide();
             $('#topic7').hide();
        }
        if ($('#choice').val()=='4')
        {
             $('#topic1').show();
             $('#topic2').show();
             $('#topic3').show();
             $('#topic4').show();
             $('#topic5').hide();
             $('#topic6').hide();
             $('#topic7').hide();
        }
        if ($('#choice').val()=='5')
        {
             $('#topic1').show();

             $('#topic2').show();

             $('#topic3').show();

             $('#topic4').show();

             $('#topic5').show();

             $('#topic6').hide();

             $('#topic7').hide();
        }
        if ($('#choice').val()=='6')

        {
             $('#topic1').show();

             $('#topic2').show();

             $('#topic3').show();

             $('#topic4').show();

             $('#topic5').show();

             $('#topic6').show();

             $('#topic7').hide();
        }
          if ($('#choice').val()=='7')
        {
             $('#topic1').show();

             $('#topic2').show();

             $('#topic3').show();

             $('#topic4').show();

             $('#topic5').show();

             $('#topic6').show();

             $('#topic7').show();
        }                        
    });
    $('#choice').change();
    });
```

Please kindly help me out here.

Comment: Basic switch case or for loop will do the work. just go through these in Jquery

Comment: Set a class for all of your elements!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#choice').change(function(){
var i;
for(i=1;i<8;i++)
{
  if(i==$(this).val())
  {
       $('#topic'+i).show();
  }
  else
  {
       $('#topic'+i).hide();
  }
}

});

$('#choice').change();
```

Edit: Improved on MrCode's Advice.

Comment: Afaik this would only show 1 `#topic[i]`, whilst hiding the all `#topic[i]` where `i != $(this).val()`.

Comment: @KooiInc Yes you are right. Based upon the conditions set in question, this should not be the accepted answer. It does not hide all the ids <= the specified one. Based on question, correct answer seems to be the one you posted. That one is best candidate for acceptance. Jeboo Scr please note

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#choice').change(function(){
        $('[id^="topic"]').hide();
        var topic = $('#choice').val();
        if (topic!='') {
            $('#topic'+topic).show();
        };
});        
$('#choice').change();
```

Comment: This is probably the cleanest way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

jquery can use selectors like this:

```
$('#choice' + i)
```

then, you can use "i" variable in your loop

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it could be done like this:

```
$('#choice').on('change', function(){
  for(var i=1;i<8;i+=1)  {
    var showhide = i <= +$(this).val() ? 'show' : 'hide';
    //                  ^convert value to numeric
    $('#topic'+i)[showhide]();
  }
 });
```

The handler determines the method to use dependent on the value of `#choice` (show or hide). For all `#topic[i]` where `i` (within the loop) is smaller then the value of `#choice` the method is `show`, for other `#topic[i]` the method is `hide`. Next, the determined method is executed, using [bracket notation](http://www.typo3-media.com/blog/javascript-object-prototype-notation.html).

Comment: Probably this could be == instead of <= ?

Comment: @Hanky Panky: that would only show the #topic[i] with chosen value and hide the rest. As far as I understand, the OP tries to show all #topic[i] with choice value <= the chosen value.

Comment: KooiInc Could you please kindly explain your code? Thanks dude

Comment: @KooiInc Yes you are right, sorry my bad i didn't look deep enough.

Comment: One more thing is that I want to make selected. Any idea dude?

Comment: @JebooScr: not sure what you mean with *I want to make selected* ... could you elaborate?

Comment: @KooiInc it meant that I insert these values to database,it is ok,but when i want to update these,it can not selected the values i have inserted.any idea?this is what i want to make the value selected.Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#choice').change(function(){
        for( var i = 0; i<8; i++) {
            if($('#choice').val() <= i) { 
                $('#topic' + i).show();
            } else {
                $('#topic' + i).hide();
            }
        }
    }
```